# What does the syntax ndarray[:,list[i]] means in python?

Tags: python, numpy, syntax

I was looking at a tutorial on the web for Python. I don't know anything about Python, so I searched and could not find the answer.

There is some code like this:

```
s = np.tanh(self.X[:,Y[t]])
```

Where, `X` is ndarray and `Y` is a List of lists (where each list is integer-type),
`np` is a numpy object, and `tanh` is the hyperbolic tangent.

What does this syntax mean?

Comment: `X` is almost certainly *not* a list of lists, but probably a numpy ndarray.

Comment: @DSM X was generated using "np.random.uniform". Sorry, as I said, I am new to python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of numpy, it can e.g. allow to access the columns, so e.g. in your example `X[:, Y[t]]`, it allows you to access the column of `X`, indexed by the value in `Y[t]`.

The `:` basically says "all rows" and the `Y[t]` specifies the column index.

Here's a simple example to see it in action:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [3]: m = np.array([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['f', 'g']])

In [4]: m[:, 0]
Out[4]: 
array(['a', 'c', 'f'], 
      dtype='|S1')

In [5]: m[:, 1]
Out[5]: 
array(['b', 'd', 'g'], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

### What if the "column index" is a list?

If you use `m[:, some_list]`, the `:` colon would ask for all rows, and then the columns would be the column indices in `some_list`, in that order

so e.g. if we want all rows, and the columns `[1, 0]` (in that order), here's what you get:

```
In [53]: m[:, [1, 0]]
Out[53]: 
array([['b', 'a'],
       ['d', 'c'],
       ['g', 'f']], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

Comment: Actually Y[t] is also a list. That means, Y itself is a list-of-lists. So, Y[t] would be [2,4,5,6,8,...]. What would be the output of X[:,Y[t]] is that case?
Possible guess ! The output can be...

m[ : , [0,1] ] => [ 'a' , 'c' , 'f' , 'b' , 'd' , 'g' ]

Am I right?

Comment: @HemendraSharma `m[:, [0,1]]` would be asking for "all rows of m, in column 0 and column 1", I added the trace in my answer to explain